# Weekly Featured Image: Aug 1, '11

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the **week of 1 August** to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days! (If you have questions about whether your photo qualifies, feel free to join our chat and post the picture there for preliminary review, as well as critiques if you so desire.)

### .: Voting Closes on July 31th at 11:59pm EDT (UTC-4) :.

---

Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1291/weekly-featured-image-jul-25-11)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/708/image-of-the-week-hall-of-fame)

---

**Submitter Rules:**

- Limit one photo per person per week.
- Include a title for the image
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row
- A specific photo may not be submitted more than four times a year.
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe.
- Do not submit any photo if you are currently featured.
- Images must be 375 x 210 px.
- Do not use this forum as a means to get critiques!
- Showcase your best works!

This contest is for the community to choose what they LIKE, with the most liked being displayed on the main site header for a week. In recent weeks, this simple submit and vote thread has become much more competitive than it really needs to be. It has also become grounds for photo critiques, which is not the intention. As such, we are adding a few additional rules when it comes to voting as well as submissions.

### PLEASE READ THE FOLLOWING, ESPECIALLY IN REGARDS TO DOWNVOTING

**Voting Rules:**

- **Up votes only!**
- Only vote up the images you like...ignore those you do not.
- DO NOT use this forum as a place for image critique. Use chat for that (you'll get far better feedback)!
- DO NOT vote down your competitors! UP VOTES ONLY! Don't like, don't vote.
- DO NOT vote if an image is improperly sized...simply write a comment noting the discrepancy, and allow the submitter to correct.

**General Tips:**

We know the image format is an odd one, and not particularly well suited to displaying your artwork. As such, we encourage you to include a link to a larger version of your image. You may host your work on sites such as Flickr, 1x.com, 500px.com, RedBubble.com, etc. to showcase larger versions.

You should include a title, something that concisely explains the image, the emotion behind them, etc. In addition to a title, voters also generally like to see additional artist comments about the image, explanation of gear and exposure settings, etc. Feel free to describe your image in addition to a title.

---

(**NOTE**: We are strongly discouraging the use of down votes. If, for some reason, a submitter is openly violating the rules and is not open to correcting their image...for example an incorrect size or improper orientation...then moderators may choose to delete such entries. Such entries are the only entries that should be down voted, if it comes to that. Please refrain from down voting such images until the last days of the contest. If we continue to see down votes on qualifying submissions, we may institute a policy that only takes into account up votes as seen when showing total up/down votes (requires 1000 rep). If we do end up having to ignore down votes, that may result in a different winner than would normally be expected, as the winner taking into account up and down votes may not have as many votes as the winner only taking into account up votes. We would much prefer not to do this, and are hoping our community can demonstrate enough honor and dignity to follow the rules.)

Comment: It says voting closes July 24th..I think this may be a mistake.

Comment: Sadly I read the NEW rules late :(

Comment: Well, downvotes a plenty already lol.

Comment: We may just have to ignore the down votes and account for only up-votes...

Comment: Looking at previous contests, downvotes don't seem to have ever actually altered the results of the contest (the guy with the most upvotes won regardless).  The only thing downvotes (esp on a entry already at 0) do is criticize in what should be a friendly contest.  Unfortunately, counting upvotes will have little effect in persuading a more jovial attitude here.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

### Tunnel Vision

[image: Copenhagen Metro tunnel]

The subway below Copenhagen, Denmark features remote operated trains, so passengers can take a seat at the front and enjoy the view through the windshield as the train shoots down the tunnels under the ancient city.

Shot handheld at 1/25, f/2.8, ISO 1600 and 70mm focal length.

Large version [here](http://kim.burgaardphotography.com/Travel/Copenhagen-July-2011/17983118_ZwbSmW#1380000401_hzw39dM).

Comment: a good one... congratulations, is an excelent photography... what camera has used for this?...

Comment: thanks! The photo was captured with a Canon 5D mark 2.

Comment: This photo is so good it should be disqualified for cheating. Oh God I don't stand a chance..

Answer (score 10):

**Just another ordinary sunset...**

[image]

A beautiful sunset that was mistaken for a dawn.
Larger version in [flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/fahad-faria/5955993213/lightbox).

Answer (score 8):

### Bored With Boarding

[image]

You can see the fullsize image on [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/seanbatten/5870256076/in/photostream/)

Comment: I don't know why this isn't higher up. It's got a very journalistic, street photography feel, and it tells a story, which is rare in these parts.

Comment: @ElendilTheTail: Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

### [lighting the sky...](http://flic.kr/p/8jrFZV)

[image]

[original in flickr](http://flic.kr/p/8jrFZV)

Answer (score 6):

**Fly drinking water**

[image]

Taken with a Canon Rebel T3, 100mm Macro Lens

Full version [here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/24996716@N00/5971526800/in/photostream/lightbox/)

Comment: and where is the water? :)

Comment: There's a bubble of it on the fly's mouth.

Comment: Oh yeah, now I see it :)

Answer (score 5):

Stones & flowers.

[image: Decorative stones]

Comment: I like this one :) do you have anything larger?

Comment: Oh, sorry. Forgot to link to the original-sized: http://enc-on-accela.deviantart.com/gallery/#/dxblby

Answer (score 3):

**Hay rolls**

[image: Hay rolls]

Shot with a borrowed 300mm f/4.5 - a natural choice for landscape photography :)

Comment: Cool shot! I like it.

Answer (score 3):

**My Wine collection**

[image]

[Large Version](https://picasaweb.google.com/pathik.thaker/MyNewMacroLens#slideshow/5630878342989833618)

Answer (score 2):

**Skyscape**

[image]

Taken from Boston, MA. Sky was very beautiful that day. Larger version on [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/navaneethkn/5959243756/in/photostream/lightbox/)